# numpy.arange on an N x 2 array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Given an `(N, 2)` array of `[start, stop]` [values](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html), I want an `(M,)` array consisting of `[np.arange(start[0], stop[0]), np.arange(start[1], stop[1], ..., np.arange(start[N - 1], stop[N - 1])]`.

For example, given `arr = np.array([[1, 3], [4, 5], [7, 8], [8, 10]])`, I want `[1, 2, 4, 7, 8, 9]`.

One method is with a for loop:

```
arr = np.array([[1, 3], [4, 5], [7, 8], [8, 10]])
out = np.zeros(0, dtype=int)
for i in range(len(arr)):
  out = np.append(out, np.arange(arr[i, 0], arr[i, 1]))
print(out)
```

Result: `[1 2 4 7 8 9]`.

Is there a more efficient and/or readable way of doing this?

Comment: Collect the arrays in a list, and do `np.hstack` once.  You could use a list comprehension.  `np.r_` is also an option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a list comprehension to collect the aranges, and then join them:

```
In [214]: alist = [[1, 3], [4, 5], [7, 8], [8, 10]]
In [215]: [np.arange(start,stop) for start,stop in alist]
Out[215]: [array([1, 2]), array([4]), array([7]), array([8, 9])]
In [216]: np.hstack(_)
Out[216]: array([1, 2, 4, 7, 8, 9])
```

There's a version of `hstack` that uses indexing syntax:

```
In [217]: np.r_[1:3, 4:5, 7:8, 8:10]
Out[217]: array([1, 2, 4, 7, 8, 9])
```

It translates the slices into `arange` calls.  It's compact, but it's not easy to use with a predefined list.

Note that I started with a list.  Starting with a (n,2) array isn't better with this kind of iteration.

With the predefined  list, first create a tuple:

```
In [225]: tup = tuple([slice(start,stop) for start, stop in alist])
In [226]: tup
Out[226]: (slice(1, 3, None), slice(4, 5, None), slice(7, 8, None), slice(8, 10, None))
In [227]: np.r_[tup]
Out[227]: array([1, 2, 4, 7, 8, 9])
```

Anyways, there isn't a way of generating multiple aranges with one call.  If the aranges are all the same length it is possible to use `np.linspace`, but not when they very in length.

We try to avoid repeated `np.append`.  It is inferior to list append.

For this sample, the pure list approach is much faster:

```
In [230]: timeit [item for start, stop in alist for item in range(start, stop)]
1.53 µs ± 26.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
In [231]: timeit np.hstack([np.arange(start,stop) for start,stop in alist])
12.7 µs ± 58.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

The array method may be faster if the individual ranges get much longer, but won't improve if the total number of ranges increases.

Comment: In my answer I have a `m` parameter, if m is higher than a certain value, numpy will be faster!

Answer (score 1):

Here the line you need.

```
[item for start, stop in [[1, 3], [4, 5], [7, 8], [8, 10]] for item in range(start, stop)]
```

You can deal with normal list to achieve this. (Don t overuse numpy, python vanilla is good too!)

For small amount of data, the numpy import don't worth it!

Time average execution:

```
import time
import numpy as np

n = 10000
m = 10
in_data = [[i, i+m] for i in range(n)]


t0 = time.time()
[item for sublist in [range(start, stop) for start, stop in in_data] for item in sublist]
print(time.time() - t0)  # 0.006821393966674805 s


t0 = time.time()
[item for start, stop in in_data for item in range(start, stop)]
print(time.time() - t0)  # 0.00554966926574707 s


t0 = time.time()
arr = np.array(in_data)
out = np.zeros(0, dtype=int)
for i in range(len(arr)):
  out = np.append(out, np.arange(arr[i, 0], arr[i, 1]))
print(time.time() - t0)  # 0.43521547317504883 s
```

Comment: Vanilla Python _is_ good, but it can be radically slower when dealing with large arrays.

Comment: Totally agree with you! But most and most slow numpy functions are used into larges for loops in programs, it slow all the execution. Just use numpy when needed and without python for/while loops is my message!

Comment: We don't expect people to write giant example inputs in their questions just to demonstrate that their inputs are large.

Comment: I think the data approximation size should be mentionned in most questions, it could change the way the answer is given!

Comment: (Also, even for a vanilla Python solution, this could be simplified to `[item for start, stop in ... for item in range(start, stop)]`.)

Comment: Likely, the OP is showing a simplified example. You're right that vanilla Python is appropriate here, but probably the in OP's real case numpy is the only viable option.

Comment: @richardec not as show in the question, the numpy.append is slow and must not be executed in a loop! For n = 100000 it takes 36.47480583190918 s (for < 0.1 s for not numpy)!!!

Comment: This approach is faster than my arange approach.  Time scaling will differ, but the pure list approach is certain valid for this problem.  `numpy` isn't always faster.